# How to use sprite mask on animated sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add the sprite mask component to my animated sprite with sprite skin but it let me choose only one sprite as a mask and there's no option for adding animation on the sprite mask. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: One way to achieve this effect might be to use multiple sprite masks, each with a different sprite, and switch between them at the desired intervals to create the illusion of an animated mask. Alternatively, you could use a custom shader to achieve this effect.

Comment: I tried in code to change the sprite of a sprite mask and it works, now I have to understand how to synchronize it with the animation but another problem now is how to use it with a sprite skin